# Read hyperparamters from lightgbm.basic.Booster object

Tags: machine-learning, lightgbm, boosting

How do you read the hyperparameters from an `lightgbm.basic.Booster` object?

The object is created from file:

```
model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
```

Stuff like `n_estimators, boosting_type, learning_rate` is not available from `model.dump_model()`